# How can I get the ip addresses of my instances inside the ECS Cluster using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecs')
response = client.list_clusters()
response1 = client.list_container_instances(
    cluster='Cluster1234',
)

print(response, response1)
```

Comment: What did you hope to get with the code you pasted? What was the output of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response from [list_container_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.list_container_instances) give you a list of container instance ARNs in `containerInstanceArns`.

You can then pass that as `containerInstances` to [describe_container_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_container_instances) to get a list of container instances and their underlying EC2 instance IDs in `containerInstances[*].ec2InstanceId`.

You can then pass those EC2 instance IDs as `InstanceIds` to [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) which will give  you, among other things, their IP addresses.

There may be a more concise way to do this, but I'm not immediately aware of it.

Here's an example:

```
import boto3

ecs = boto3.client('ecs', region_name='us-east-1')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')

rc = ecs.list_clusters()

for cluster in rc['clusterArns']:
    ci = ecs.list_container_instances(cluster=cluster)

    if len(ci['containerInstanceArns']) > 0:
        r2 = ecs.describe_container_instances(
            cluster=cluster,
            containerInstances=ci['containerInstanceArns'])

        ids = [x['ec2InstanceId'] for x in r2['containerInstances']]

        r3 = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=ids)

        for r in r3['Reservations']:
            for i in r['Instances']:
                print("{0}: instance {1}, state {2}, AMI {3}, private IP {4}, public IP {5}".format(
                    cluster.split('/')[-1],
                    i['InstanceId'],
                    i['State']['Name'],
                    i['ImageId'],
                    i['PrivateIpAddress'] if 'PrivateIpAddress' in i else 'n/a',
                    i['PublicIpAddress'] if 'PublicIpAddress' in i else 'n/a'))
```

This will yield an output something like this:

```
cluster-101: instance i-01234e5ea85f30ba7, state running, AMI ami-045f1b3f87ed83659, private IP 10.0.0.222, public IP 54.166.303.1
cluster-101: instance i-023452ab72c755e01, state running, AMI ami-045f1b3f87ed83659, private IP 10.0.1.333, public IP 54.166.202.2
cluster-101: instance i-03456645cc5d9b19d, state running, AMI ami-045f1b3f87ed83659, private IP 10.0.1.444, public IP 54.166.101.3
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes sense but how can I pass from one o/p to other i/p, like from container instances to describe_container_instances

Comment: Thanks Jarmod. This works fine, but incase if I want to list AMI id it is showing a error by adding i[Imageid'] to the print statement.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write i[‘ImageId’]. What error does it show?

Comment: Did a small mistake. It works, here instead of hardcoding the cluster is there a way where I can take my cluster from ecs.list_clusters() and include my cluster name in the o/p.

Comment: I've attached updated code. It should be quite simple for you to make any additional changes that you require.

Comment: @Ram Hi Ram, if this answers your question then please accept it as the answer so others know it has been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers